# Is there an -Os equivalent in Rust?

Tags: ios, rust

I see that I can select an optimization level between 0 and 3 for Rust, but I would like an -Os option as well. The reason is that not only is it possible that the -Os code would be faster, but also I'm looking at Rust for iOS, where keeping your code size small for the App Store is very important (a lot of the code gets encrypted before compression, so it can't effectively be compressed, and we have to consider people downloading the app where bandwidth is at a premium, e.g. on poor 3G connections). To me, this seems like a blocker from using Rust for large-scale iOS development.

Comment: `rustc -C help | grep opt-level`

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks